# Not using SafeAreaView but still it's avoiding the top notch of iPhone in react-native

Tags: react-native

I am not using SafeAreaView anywhere inside my code but still i am getting a blank white line at the top of every screen inside my app. I tried everything but it's still giving me the top white line .Can someone please help me ??(https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3mmq.jpg)

Since it is an introslider i want to show it  on the the full screen with full screen height and width including top notch.

Comment: did you use flex:1 or width:"100%" height:"100%"

Comment: yes I tried it but i didn't work

Comment: Any other answers???